# Python: Finding the most recent entry

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I need to find the most recent entry using the timestamp.

Relevant data below. Python 2.7

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for dt in data:
#cleaning up data

print data[3]['Timestamp']
```

Output:

```
u'2017/08/17 5:49:19 PM EST'
```

Comment: Would you mind removing the irrelevant parts of your code please?

Comment: I hope that is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a timestamp column, you can get the latest timestamp using max:

```
data.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data.Timestamp)
data.Timestamp.max()
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: That has been the bigest problem I have run in to, how to convert from str to integers for the timestamp

Comment: @user8585830: I've added a line to convert to datetime for you.